# function of this code in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

Can anyone explain as what this piece of code functions as

```
void ClearScreen()
{
        HANDLE hOut;
        COORD Position;
        hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        Position.X = 0;
        Position.Y = 0;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, Position);
}
```

What is the use of this code every time it is called in maze generation or snakes's game?

Comment: Presumably, it clears a screen.

Comment: It executes each line and doesn't return anything. What *exactly* do you want to know?!

Comment: It is most likely a windows.h function for setting a handle to the output, and using it to change the position of the cursor. It does not look like it should clear the screen, only overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what library they are using, but it clears the screen, gets a handle (?), and moves the cursor position to 0, 0.